# Why is the Bigdecimal(double d) construction still around?

Tags: java, api, bigdecimal

I've noticed substantial pain over this constructor (even here on Stack Overflow). People use it even though the documentation clearly states:

> *The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable*
>   http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(double)

I've even seen a [JSR-13](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=13) being [APPROVED](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/results?id=2758) with a recommendation stating:

> *Existing specifications that might be deprecated: We propose deprecating the BigDecimal(double) constructor, which currently gives results that are different to the Double.toString() method.*

Despite all this, the constructor has not yet been deprecated.

I'd love to hear any views on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deprecation is deprecated. Parts of APIs are only marked deprecated in exceptional cases.

So, run FindBugs as part of your build process. FindBugs has a detector PlugIn API and is also open source (LGPL, IIRC).

Comment: .. And after long consideration I feel that is the only possible answer -  A policy from the Keepers of the API. Nothing else could completely explain this.

Comment: Why is deprecation deprecated? I have just found http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/deprecation/deprecation.html and it doesn't say anything about that.

Answer (score 21):

Considering the behavior of [`BigDecimal(double)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(double)) is correct, in my opinion, I'm not too sure it really would be such a problem.

I wouldn't exactly agree with the wording of the documentation in the `BigDecimal(double)` constructor:

> The results of this constructor can be
>   somewhat **unpredictable**. One might
>   assume that writing `new
>   BigDecimal(0.1)` in Java creates a
>   `BigDecimal` which is exactly equal to
>   `0.1` (an unscaled value of `1`, with a scale of `1`), but it is actually equal
>   to
>   `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`.

(Emphasis added.)

Rather than saying *unpredictable*, I think the wording should be **unexpected**, and even so, this would be unexpected behavior for those who are not aware of the limitations of representation of decimal numbers with [floating point values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point).

As long as one keeps in mind that floating point values cannot represent all decimal values with precision, the value returned by using `BigDecimal(0.1)` being `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625` actually makes sense.

If the `BigDecimal` object instantiated by the `BigDecimal(double)` constructor is consistent, then I would argue that the result is predictable.

My guess as to why the `BigDecimal(double)` constructor is not being deprecated is because the behavior can be considered correct, and as long as one knows how floating point representations work, the behavior of the constructor is not too surprising.

Comment: Great arguments! ">as long as one knows how floating point representations work" ... guess this sentence eliminates ~95% of the programming world (probably more). Preventing those 95% of programmers causing millions(?) of dollars in accounting errors might probably be what prompted that recommendation in JSR-13 :)

Comment: following that reasoning (not only) double and float must be removed ASAP

Comment: It's important for computer scientists to remember that not all floating point values can be represented, but I don't think that means that this constructor is good. While some floating point values can't be represented by a double, IMO there should be no reason that the ones that can would be misrepresented when using the double constructor. In fact, it's even worse that other documentation within this class hints at the constructor's weakness http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf(double)

Answer (score 1):

That particular constructor, like all floating point operations, is an approximation.  It's not really broken, it just has shortcomings.
Just do your research, approach it with care, and you won't get any surprises.  You run into exactly the same thing when assigning decimal literals to doubles/floats.

Comment: Good point, it is like a landmine for unsuspecting developers. Landmines never served anyone in the long run.. which is why the JSR I guess...