# Convert double to BigDecimal and set BigDecimal Precision

Tags: java, double, bigdecimal

In Java, I want to take a double value and convert it to a `BigDecimal` and print out its String value to a certain precision.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double d=-.00012;
        System.out.println(d+""); //This prints -1.2E-4

        double c=47.48000;
        BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(c);
        System.out.println(b.toString()); 
        //This prints 47.47999999999999687361196265555918216705322265625 
    }
}
```

It prints this huge thing:

> 47.47999999999999687361196265555918216705322265625

and not

> 47.48

The reason I'm doing the `BigDecimal` conversion is sometimes the double value will contain a lot of decimal places (i.e. `-.000012`) and the when converting the double to a String will produce scientific notation `-1.2E-4`.  I want to store the String value in non-scientific notation.

I want to have BigDecimal always have two units of precision like this: "47.48".  Can BigDecimal restrict precision on conversion to string?

Comment: Note: BigDecimal will also sometimes use the scientific notation (I believe for number < 10^-6)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It prints 47.48000 if you use another [MathContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/MathContext.html):

```
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(d, MathContext.DECIMAL64);
```

Just pick the context you need.

Comment: Using the double constructor is not recommended.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056722/why-is-the-bigdecimaldouble-d-construction-still-around

Comment: BigDecimal b = BigDecimal.valueOf(d);

Comment: @ rvazquezglez like your solution

Comment: Still flawed for other values. For example `new BigDecimal( 1E-11, MathContext.DECIMAL64).toPlainString()` prints `0.000000000009999999999999999`, but `BigDecimal.valueOf` works as expected.

Answer (score 167):

The reason of such behaviour is that the string that is printed is the exact value - probably not what you expected, but that's the real value stored in memory - it's just a limitation of floating point representation.

According to javadoc, BigDecimal(double val) constructor behaviour can be unexpected if you don't take into consideration this limitation:

> The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable. One
>   might assume that writing new BigDecimal(0.1) in Java creates a
>   BigDecimal which is exactly equal to 0.1 (an unscaled value of 1, with
>   a scale of 1), but it is actually equal to
>   0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. This is because 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a double (or, for that
>   matter, as a binary fraction of any finite length). Thus, the value
>   that is being passed in to the constructor is not exactly equal to
>   0.1, appearances notwithstanding.

So in your case, instead of using

```
double val = 77.48;
new BigDecimal(val);
```

use

```
BigDecimal.valueOf(val);
```

Value that is returned by BigDecimal.valueOf is equal to that resulting from invocation of `Double.toString(double)`.

Comment: Ran into the exact same problem today and this is IMHO the most suitable answer! Thanks!

Comment: I suggest to add `.stripTrailingZeros()` after `BigDecimal.valueOf(val)` to ommit trailling zeros. exemple: `BigDecimal.valueOf(15.0).stripTrailingZeros();` -> 15 (instead of 15.0 if you don't call `.stripTrailingZeros()`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 20):

You want to try `String.format("%f", d)`, which will print your double in decimal notation. Don't use `BigDecimal` at all.

Regarding the precision issue: You are first storing `47.48` in the `double c`, then making a new `BigDecimal` from that `double`. The loss of precision is in assigning to `c`. You could do

```
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("47.48")
```

to avoid losing any precision.

Answer (score 11):

Why not :

```
b = b.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Comment: why not BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(c).setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

Answer (score 6):

It's printing out the actual, exact value of the `double`.

`Double.toString()`, which converts `double`s to `String`s, does *not* print the exact decimal value of the input -- if `x` is your double value, it prints out exactly enough digits that `x` is the closest `double` to the value it printed.

The point is that there *is no such `double`* as 47.48 exactly.  Doubles store values as *binary* fractions, not as decimals, so it can't store exact decimal values.  (That's what `BigDecimal` is for!)

Answer (score 5):

In Java 9 the following is deprecated:

`BigDecimal.valueOf(d).`<strike>setScale</strike>`(2, BigDecimal.`<strike>ROUND_HALF_UP</strike>`);`

instead use:

```
BigDecimal.valueOf(d).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Example:

```
    double d = 47.48111;

    System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(d)); //Prints: 47.48111

    BigDecimal bigDecimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(d).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    System.out.println(bigDecimal); //Prints: 47.48
```

Answer (score 3):

**The String.format syntax helps us convert doubles and BigDecimals to strings of whatever precision.**

This java code:

```
double dennis = 0.00000008880000d;
System.out.println(dennis);
System.out.println(String.format("%.7f", dennis));
System.out.println(String.format("%.9f", new BigDecimal(dennis)));
System.out.println(String.format("%.19f", new BigDecimal(dennis)));
```

Prints:

```
8.88E-8
0.0000001
0.000000089
0.0000000888000000000
```

Answer (score 2):

```
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(c).setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap using `BigDecimal.valueOf()`:

```
double d = 47.48111;
BigDecimal.valueOf(d)
```