# Can I raise a Java BigInteger to a double/float power?

Tags: java, double, biginteger

I'm a .NET developer, but apparently no library exists to do this in .NET. So, is there any BigInteger implementation in Java that allows raising a BigInteger to a double exponent:

```
BigInteger result = BigInteger.pow( base, dblExponent);
// Base is a BigInteger, dblExponent is a double.
```

Comment: The mathematical result would usually not be an integer, so providing such a function would need to make a dubious decision about how to interpret it. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @DanielFischer That is not a problem, in my case I would always generate something that has a fractional part .00000 etc. So i can then convert to integer without losing data.
But my question was whether such a function exists.

Comment: So raising your huge number to the nearest integer isn't precise enough? do you mind saying what you need this sort of large number with super precision for?

Comment: @Jonathan That it _usually_ would not produce an integer is the reason (well, one of the reasons at least) that such a function is not provided by the standard libraries. So in your application, `base` is always a `k`-th power, and you want to raise it to the `n/k`-th power? `n`-th power exists, so you need a `k`-th root. I don't think `BigInteger` directly provides one, but it might be provided by some library out there. If not, that's much easier to write than arbitrary `double` exponents.

Comment: .NET also has BigInteger, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx

Comment: As far as I can tell from looking through the API docs of `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` such an operation is not available. I don’t know of nay 3rd party libraries that offer it either, but you may go searching.

Comment: `BigInteger` and its fellow `BigDecimal` are designed to give you full precision of your numbers. An integer raised to the power of a double in most cases will not yield a rational number, so full precision simply isn’t possible. So your request doesn’t *really* make sense.

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
BigInteger base = new BigInteger("10");
double base1 = base.doubleValue();
double dblExponent = 10;
double res = pow(base1, dblExponent);
BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(res);
```

but pay attention to [precision issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395281/convert-double-to-bigdecimal-precision-issue)

EDIT:
you have to import this library:
   import static java.lang.Math.pow;

Comment: Thank you but that's not what I'm looking for.
The result in your code cannot be bigger than Double.MaxValue.
My result BigInteger would be several hundred digits long. I need to raise a BigInteger to a floating-value power.

Comment: OK so I think with JDK 1.6 it sounds impossible. From Oracle documentation: public BigDecimal pow(int n)
Returns a BigDecimal whose value is (thisn), The power is computed exactly, to unlimited precision.
The parameter n must be in the range 0 through 999999999, inclusive. ZERO.pow(0) returns ONE. Note that future releases may expand the allowable exponent range of this method.