# How to raise double to bigInteger in java

Tags: java, biginteger

I need to calculate the `$a^b$` where `a` is `BigInteger` and `b` is `double` is it possible to do so in java?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751167/can-i-raise-a-java-biginteger-to-a-double-float-power

Comment: Raising an integer to fractional powers results in a real number.  You want to get a `BigDouble` as a result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java's BigDecimal.power(BigDecimal exponent): Is there a Java library that does it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441769/javas-bigdecimal-powerbigdecimal-exponent-is-there-a-java-library-that-does)

Comment: thank you I read the previous question and answers, there is no clear answer is it allowed or not in java. Thank you once again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the standard Java library does not provide any way to compute powers with arbitraty precision.

If you don't really need arbitrary precision and double precision is enough, you could use `Math.pow(double, double)`.

If your exponent is actually an integer, you could try `BigInteger.pow(int)`:

```
BigInteger result = new BigInteger("312413431431431431434314134").pow(5);
```

And if you actually need arbitraty precision power operation, you'll have to look at some library. For example, there is Apfloat: https://github.com/mtommila/apfloat

You could do something like this:

```
BigDecimal base = new BigDecimal("12341341341341341341341343414134134");
double exponent = 1.5;
Apfloat apfloatBase = new Apfloat(base);
Apfloat apfloatExponent = new Apfloat(exponent);
Apfloat result = ApfloatMath.pow(apfloatBase, apfloatExponent);
```

Javadocs: http://www.apfloat.org/apfloat_java/docs/org/apfloat/Apfloat.html
http://www.apfloat.org/apfloat_java/docs/org/apfloat/ApfloatMath.html