# new BigDecimal(double) vs new BigDecimal(String)

Tags: java, bigdecimal, double-precision

When `BigDecimal` is used with an input of `double` and `BigDecimal` with an input of `String` different results seem to appear.

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(0.333333333);
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(0.666666666);

BigDecimal c = new BigDecimal("0.333333333");
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("0.666666666");

BigDecimal x = a.multiply(b);
BigDecimal y = c.multiply(d);

System.out.println(x);
System.out.println(y);
```

x outputs as

```
0.222222221777777790569747304508155316795087227497352441864147715340493949298661391367204487323760986328125
```

while y is

```
0.222222221777777778
```

Am I wrong in saying that this is because of double imprecision?  But since this is a `BigDecimal`, shouldn't it be the same?

Comment: have a look on a,b and c,d ... this is already different ;) have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395281/convert-double-to-bigdecimal-and-set-bigdecimal-precision

Comment: This is because `double` has limited precision; That's IEEE 754 for you.

Comment: you can correct it by using `.setScale(10, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Am I wrong in saying that this is because of double imprecision?

You are absolutely right, this is exactly because of `double`'s imprecision.

> But since this is a `BigDecimal`, shouldn't it be the same?

No, it shouldn't. The error is introduced the moment you create `new BigDecimal(0.333333333)`, because `0.333333333` constant already has an error embedded in it. At that point there is nothing you can do to fix this representation error: the proverbial horse is out of the barn by then, so it's too late to close the doors.

When you pass a `String`, on the other hand, the decimal representation matches the string exactly, so you get a different result.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is floating point error. The problem is that the literals `0.333333333` and `0.666666666` are represented as doubles before being passed as an argument to `BigDecimal` --- notably, `BigDecimal`'s constructor takes a `double` as an argument.

This is supported by the standard, which says that [floating point literals default to `double` unless otherwise specified](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2).

Comment: It is not a floating point _error_.  The floating point code is behaving exactly the way it is intended to behave.  The only problem is with the programmer's _expectation_ of how it will behave.  The "problem" is that `0.333333333` does not represent the same rational number that is represented by `new BigDecimal("0.333333333")`.  But, that is not a bug, and it can't be "fixed" except by changing the Java Language Specification such that  `0.333333333` is no longer interpreted as an IEEE binary double.

Comment: @jameslarge I'm aware of how IEEE binary doubles work --- the imprecision that results from using them is typically referred to as "error." See, for example, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Machine_precision_and_backward_error_analysis), or the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). This is error in the sense of [statistical error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors_and_residuals_in_statistics), not `FileNotFoundError`.

Comment: Oh,... right...  _that_ kind of error.  I guess I've been kind of preoccupied with software defects lately (please, don't ask me why), and I'm starting to see them even where they are not.

Answer (score 5):

Java docs has its answer. According to Java docs of [BigDecimal(double val)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(double))

> The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable. One
>   might assume that writing new BigDecimal(0.1) in Java creates a
>   BigDecimal which is exactly equal to 0.1 (an unscaled value of 1, with
>   a scale of 1), but it is actually equal to
>   0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. This is because 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a double.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a double variable in any way, in most cases it won't be the value you have defined, but the closest possible binary representation. You are passing a double to the constructor, so already providing that small imprecision.