# BigDecimal as String in Swagger defenition

Tags: java, json, swagger, bigdecimal

I would like to define an object with **BigDecimal** as String in *swagger.json*

Right now I can do

```
"MyObject": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "amountOfMoney": {
       "type": "string",
       "pattern": "d+([.]d+)?"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "title": "MyObject"
}
```

Another way, I can Define amountOfMoney as a number.

```
"MyObject": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "amountOfMoney": {
      "type": "number"
      "minimum": 0.0,
      "maximum": 100.0,
      "exclusiveMinimum": false,
      "exclusiveMaximum": false
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "title": "MyObject"
}
```

Java class defention

```
public class MyObject {

    private BigDecimal amountOfMoney;
    private String name;

    //Getters, setters.
}
```

How do I enforce **minimum** and **maximum** validation, like in the second example?

### Update

We use springfox 2.8.0.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

We have configuration (as a Spring bean), where I could add a substitute.

```
Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
    .select()
    .paths(PathSelectors.any())
    .build()
    .pathMapping("/")
    // see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40737219
    .directModelSubstitute(MyObject .class, String.class)
```

I can even use substitute `BigDecimal` by `String`! I would like to have format for that string to ensure I will get numbers between min and max.

[It is  not recommended to create BigDecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54681006/4587961) from numbers.  [Another link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29632568/4587961)

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/

[Swagger documentation for Spring Pageable interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35404329/swagger-documentation-for-spring-pageable-interface/40737219#40737219)

For example, there is string format for dates. How do I make one for numbers?

Comment: What is stopping you from doing the thing you like?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I would like to have validation of minimum and maximum.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validating JSON against Swagger API schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39275947/validating-json-against-swagger-api-schema)