# Why is BigDecimal returning an approximation of my large double in Java?

Tags: java

I'd like to round my large double so the first thing I decided to do, was to convert it into a BigDecimal in the following way.

```
    BigDecimal amount = BigDecimal
        .valueOf(getAmount())
        .setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    System.out.println(amount);
```

In my example, `getAmount()` returns `123456789123123424113.31`.

Therefore, I expect the exact same value to be printed out by my snippet.

Instead, I get the following value:

```
123456789123123430000.00
```

Can someone explain why BigDecimal is returning an approximation of my double?

Comment: What happens if you just `System.out.println(getAmount())`?

Comment: You may need to choose a different `MathContext` given the large number you're dealing with. Have a look at this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12395405/3415090

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In my example, `getAmount()` returns `123456789123123424113.31`.

No, it does not. That is not a value that a `double` can represent exactly.

You can easily verify that with this code:

```
double d = 123456789123123424113.31d;
System.out.println(d);
```

Which outputs

```
1.2345678912312343E20
```

This value has the minimum amount of digits to uniquely distinguish it from any other `double` value. Meaning that there aren't any more relevant digits in that `double`. You've already lost the precision **before** converting the value to `BigDecimal`.

While an integer data type such as `long` and `int` can exactly represent every (integer) value within its range, the same can't be said about floating point numbers: they have an immense range of values that they can represent, but at the cost of not being able to represent every possible value within the range. Effectively there's a limited number of digits that a floating point number can represent (about 16 decimal digits for `double` and about 7 decimal digits for `float`). Everything else will be cut off.

If you need arbitrary precision then something like `BigDecimal` can help: it will allocate as much memory as necessary to hold all digits (or round according to your specification, if required), making it much more complex but also more powerful.

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("123456789123123424113.31");
System.out.println(bd);
```

will print

```
123456789123123424113.31
```

Make sure not to initialize the `BigDecimal` from a `double` value, as you'll only get the cut-off value even then.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Hmmm, so what would be the correct way to store a large decimal value without losing precision?

Comment: @p4t keep it as a `String` and convert it back and forth from / to `BigDecimal` when needed.

Comment: @p4t: use `BigDecimal` all throughout your calculation and never convert anything to a `double` (not even for intermediate results). Also make sure those `BigDecimal` are not **initialized** from `double` values (use the `String` constructor if you need decimal points).

Comment: @p4t a `String` as return value from `getAmount()` along with the parameterized constructor of `BigDecimal` could work... Try to sys-out the `doubleValue()` of `BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("123456789123123424113.31");`