# BigDecimal constructor performance - string vs numeric

Tags: java, performance, bigdecimal

```
new BigDecimal("10000");
new BigDecimal(10000);
```

I know the string constructor is used if the number is bigger than the compiler would accept, but are either of the constructors faster than the other?

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself? Call these constructors several thousand times and measure the needed time. And maybe read this: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/513259)

Comment: See http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/math/BigDecimal.java

Comment: According to this SQ question the double constructor is deprecated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056722/why-is-the-bigdecimaldouble-d-construction-still-around

Comment: @bish No one uses that constructor here, so it isn't important :).

Comment: @rossum I already looked at that actually ;) but it didn't make that much sense.

Comment: logically, second constructor must be faster

Comment: @AndrewTobilko that's what I thought but I wanted to be sure

Comment: @MCMastery, open class `BigDecimal` and compare those two constructors, what is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look at source code.

```
public BigDecimal(int val) {
    intCompact = val;
}

public BigDecimal(String val) {
    this(val.toCharArray(), 0, val.length());
}

public BigDecimal(char[] in, int offset, int len) {
       ...very long
}
```

Obviously, who is faster.

Answer (score 4):

Passing a `String` to the constructor of `BigDecimal` requires a parsing of the `String` and a check char by char.

Passing an int is faster because it results only in a single assignment.

In any case the time difference is not signifiant.

Here the code of `BigDecimal` with an `int` parameter:

```
public BigDecimal(int val) {
    intCompact = val;
}
```

The code of `BigDecimal` constructor with a `String` calls `BigDecimal(char[], int, int)` that has around 140 rows of code.

Comment: Still wondering why this answer that was posted 15 mins back had no upvotes even though it is better than the accepted answer. +1 from me.

Answer (score 4):

> I know the string constructor is used if the number is bigger than the compiler would accept

That's not the only reason for using the `String` constructor. Another reason for using the `String` constructor is to keep the value as-is when the `BigDecimal` is created.

If you don't really care about precision, you should stick to using `double` instead of `BigDecimal`.

> but are either of the constructors faster than the other

This is something you have to find out yourself by benchmarking your code. That being said, you should prefer using the `valueOf` method instead of creating a new `BigDecimal` since `valueOf` will return cached values. (Currently, this ranges from 0 to 10 but this range can be higher for different JVM implementations and future implementations of the HotSpot VM as well so you are better of using `valueOf`)

Answer (score 1):

The Constructor new BigDecimal(10000) should be faster because it does not have to convert a string into a number. The under-the-hood there has to be a cast or another call to a string function which would cause some additional overhead.

```
public class benchmark {

    public static void main(String [ ] args) {
        timeFunction();
    }

static void timeFunction() {
     long startTime = System.nanoTime();

     BigDecimal v1 = new BigDecimal("10000");
     System.out.println("new BigDecimal(\"10000\") : " + (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000 + " ms");

     startTime = System.nanoTime();

     BigDecimal v2 = new BigDecimal(10000);
     System.out.println("new BigDecimal(10000) : " + (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000 + " ms");
}

}
```

OUTPUT

```
new BigDecimal("10000") : 4 ms
new BigDecimal(10000) : 0 ms
```

Comment: no-no, very bad way. I would advise [**jmh**](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/)

Comment: Microbenchmark are strongly influenced by many factors. The best way is to repeat the code several time before timing it. But in microbenchmarks creation of new Objects is really influenced by garbage collector. So the best is to microbenchmark eventually the code inside the constructor... not the constructor itself

Comment: I agree with Andrew, this may not be the best way to track benchmarks if you want a true analysis of the time difference, however, it demonstrates that the Big Decimal using string will take longer.

Answer (score 0):

Find the time difference yourself & analyse. Like :-

```
BigDecimal big = null;
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    big = new BigDecimal("10000");
}
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("time Taken In String : " + (endTime - startTime));

startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    big = new BigDecimal(10000);
}
endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("time Taken in Numeric : " + (endTime - startTime));
```

PS:- Keep in consideration the *Garbage Collection*. Consider the above code as a reference only.

Comment: That code benchmark can be heavily conditioned by garbage collector. Microbenchmarks with a great creation of new Objects are not reliable

Comment: no-no, bad way. I would advise [**jmh**](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/)